# Python String Formatting - replacing parameters with and incrementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Given the following string template and desired result, is there a simple (one-liner-type) way in Python to achieve this?
I would want id to be incremented after/before a replacement.

```
"fruit-{id} fruit-{id} fruit-{id}"
"fruit-1 fruit-2 fruit-3"
```

Update:
I realize I did not describe the problem very well and did not pick a good example. The template(s) are not usually regular like the fruit example.

It could be like...

```
"Lorem{id} ipsum dolor{id} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit{id}, sed do eiusmod{id} tempor incididunt..."
```

...where it is unclear how many id's there will be in the string.

Comment: I edited the question above since I was not precise enough. So far rassar's answer would work the best I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is always in the format `"fruit-{id} fruit-{id} fruit-{id}"`then you can't use the builtin `str.format` because it relies on the variables being different. You would have to implement your own format function, something like this (using the `re` module):

```
def format_str(s, target="{id}"):
    i = 1
    while target in s:
        s = re.subn(target, str(i), s, count=1)[0]
        i += 1
    return s
```

Comment: See my comment on the other answer. You can generate the format string itself on the fly as well as the list of ids.

Comment: @user2896976 Gotcha, did not know that variables could be anonymous in string.format. Would have saved a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

In this case format() is your friend.

**Usage**

Input ->
`'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')` |
Output -> `one two`

In your case you can use it by doing

```py
string = "fruit-{} fruit-{} fruit-{}".format(1, 2, 3)
print(string)
```

Outputs `fruit-1 fruit-2 fruit-3`

Comment: You can also support an arbitrary amount of elements (id's): https://repl.it/repls/DimgreyAstonishingBovine

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

list_of_ids = ['1','2','3','4','5']

list_of_fruits = [re.sub('id',nos,'fruit-id') for nos in list_of_ids]
//['fruit-1', 'fruit-2', 'fruit-3' ...]
```

You can use a list comprehension and regex to replace items. To reverse it:

```
[re.sub('[0-9]','id',fruit) for fruit in list_of_fruits]
```